# How is Amazon loading next page without URL?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to web scrape the amazon deals page but the problem is that I'm unable to get the URL for the next page. Here is the link to the Amazon [today's deals page](https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/). At the bottom of the page, there is pagination but when I inspected the page, there is no URL. The href tag only contains "#" in the URL which should only load the page to the top. How is Amazon able to move to the next page? is there any hidden URL? I couldn't find anything using the Network tab in the Inspect menu as well. I'm adding the picture below to show the code of pagination.

[image]

Comment: It probably doesn't load a separate page. You can watch the Network panel of developer console and see what URLs are loaded. It probably loads JSON or XML for each page

Comment: Can you please share some steps or tips using which I can inspect it? I am unable to find anything. There is "https://www.amazon.com/xa/dealcontent/v2/GetDeals" but it doesn't have all the products which is strange.

Comment: How did you verify that the `GetDeals` endpoint does not contain all the products? I just checked the request and it looks like it is getting a full page worth of products each time it is requested

Answer (score 2):

Probably some JavaScript wizardry they are running in the background. # seems like a placeholder. Check out the JavaScript code, and there might be more clues there.

Comment: Can you please share some steps or tips using which I can inspect it?

Comment: Sure. Assuming you have a modern browser, you can look at the network tab in the inspecting tools. If you select "js", you can typically see all the JavaScript. It may also be hidden in more files transferred or other requests, as amazon is trying very hard for you to fail . If you are using python, there are several libraries that can help [link](https://pypi.org/search/?q=amazon+scrape)

Comment: I did try searching for a URL in the Network tab but was unable to find anything. There is "amazon.com/xa/dealcontent/v2/GetDeals" but it doesn't have all the products which is strange. The libraries can scrap a lot of things but not what I am looking for.

Comment: Amazon is hard. They have a lot of things in place to prevent scrapers.

Comment: I agree with you. Scrapping on Amazon has been very much challenging. Cannot even make simple projects.